# How to achieve 'Test connection' functionality of IIS application basic settings page?

Tags: c#, iis

I have been trying to manipulate the settings (like app pool name, virtual directories and sites) of the applications hosted in IIS.
I have been successfully able to read/write the basic properties of the applications.
However, I am not able to *test the connection* for an application. What I want to achieve is to test whether the *authentication* and *authorization* test passes for an application. The screenshot attached shows the idea.
I can perform the test manually using the *properties* page of the application and then selecting *Test Connection*.
I want to achieve the same functionality using C#.

[image]